# How do VGA control signals work in Verilog/HDL?

Tags: verilog, fpga, system-verilog

I'm an FPGA beginner and have trouble understanding how VGA control 
signals and VGA interact, and how to correctly generate VGA control 
signals (with Verilog) for more complicated specifications:

1. Seemingly, the low portions in horizontal- and vertical- sync signals 
   correspond to transitioning from one row to the next, and transitioning 
   from the bottom-right corner to the upper-left corner, respectively. But 
   is the VGA "controlled" by those low signals? Do those low signals 
   "tell" the VGA to switch to next row or jump back to the starting point?
2. Are the back porch and front porch there to satisfy setup time and 
   hold time? Are the durations of porches given in VGA timing table only 
   required minima (i.e. can I set the porches to be much longer than the 
   given values in the timing table?)
3. This is what confuses me the most: From the two continuous 
   horizontal- and vertical- sync signals, how on earth does the VGA know 
   (or do I know) exactly which *point* on screen it is displaying? If timing 
   is the only factor, does that mean I must pay a lot of attention to 
   match RPG control signals and h-sync and v-sync signals perfectly? If 
   the answer is yes, then I have even more problems which I can only 
   describe using my assignment as an example:

In this assignment we use a built-in 50MHz clock of an FPGA (Spartan starter board) and the pixels of the VGA is specified to be 800x600. The framerate is specified to be 72Hz.

The VGA timing table gives the following sync signal structures:

h-sync:
| 0---back-porch(104)---103 | 104---display(800)---903 | 904---front-porch(16)---919 | 920__pulse width(120)__1039 |

v-sync:
| 0---back-porch(23)---22 | 23---display(600)---622 | 623---front-porch(37)---659 | 660__pulse width(6)__665 |

This seems to mean that for each pixel in a row on screen I spend 1 
clock cycle (20ns) on it. However, for many complicated cases, I would 
want to control the color of a pixel depending on its location on screen 
and perhaps a lot of additional conditions such as the relation of 
current position with another location, certain states, etc. Now, if the location of the pixel depends on horizontal and vertical pixel counters, and the color depends further on the location, how can I match them in time? Also, what if my logic has to spend more than 20ns to decide the color of a pixel? Will that completely crash the image on the VGA screen?

Actually I've somehow completed my assignment, but I find my code messy 
and I totally have no idea why it worked:

For example, a portion of the assignment required us to show a star that 
changes its color every 0.5sec. My implementation looks like:

```
//----------------pixel counters----------------
always@(posedge CLK or posedge RESET) begin
    if(RESET) h_count <= 11'd 0;
    else if (h_count >= 11'd 1039) h_count <= 11'd 0;
    else h_count <= h_count + 11'd 1;
end

always@(posedge CLK or posedge RESET) begin
    if(RESET) v_count <= 10'd 0;
    else if (v_count >= 10'd 665) v_count <= 10'd 0;
    else if (h_count == 11'd 1039) v_count <= v_count + 10'd 1;
    else v_count <= v_count;
end

//----------------h- and v- sync----------------
always@(posedge CLK or posedge RESET) begin 
  if(RESET) VGA_HSYNC <= 1'b 0;
  else VGA_HSYNC <= (h_count >= 11'd 0) & (h_count <= 11'd 919);
end

always@(posedge CLK or posedge RESET) begin 
  if(RESET) VGA_VSYNC <= 1'b 0;
  else VGA_VSYNC <= (v_count >= 10'd 0) & (v_count <= 10'd 659);
end

//----------------a frame counter and a flag----------------
always@(posedge CLK or posedge RESET) begin
    if(RESET) frame_count <= 6'd 0;
    else if (frame_count >= 6'd 49) frame_count <= 6'd 0;
    else if(v_count == 10'd 665) frame_count <= frame_count + 6'd 1;
    else frame_count <= frame_count;
end

always@(posedge CLK or posedge RESET) begin
    if(RESET) color_flag <= 1'd 0;
    else if (frame_count == 6'd 49) color_flag <= ~(color_flag);
    else color_flag <= color_flag;
end

//----------------RGB control----------------
always@(posedge CLK or posedge RESET) begin
    if(RESET) VGA_RGB <=  3'b 000;
    else if(display) begin //display is high when counters in valid range
        casez({tree, star, snow})  //these are outputs from submodules that decides the "shapes" of objects on screen
            3'b ??1: VGA_RGB <= 3'b 111;  //white snow
            3'b ?10: VGA_RGB <= (color_flag) ? (3'b 110) : (3'b 111);
                //switching between yellow and white
            3'b 100: VGA_RGB <= 3'b 010;  //green tree
            default: VGA_RGB <= 3'b 001;  //blue background
    endcase
  end
  else VGA_RGB <= 3'b 000;  //for transitions
end
```

It seems to me that my h_count and v_count directly decides my VGA_HSYNC and VGA_VSYNC. But my VGA_RGB depends at least on color_flag, which further depends on frame_count, which depends on h_count and v_count. Shouldn't that cause delay of a few clock cycles? The code was synthesizable and did produced what I wanted to display. But how on earth did my VGA_RGB sync with VGA_HSYNC and VGA_VSYNC in time??? Am I overthinking this issue? Or was I just lucky? What did I miss?

Comment: To partially answer your question, usually you want to have some block of memory (either on or off-chip) to store your pixel data. That way, you can operate on it (making changes, updating, etc.) independently of the VGA controller, and can take as long as you want/need to make any changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of your questions can be explained by the fact that VGA is an analog standard which was originally designed to run on analog devices. The h-sync and v-sync pulses simply trigger their respective deflection coils back to their start positions while the front and back porches account for the fact that the beam starts and ends outside the visible portion of the screen.

With respect to accuracy, it's better than it used to be: sending a badly timed VGA signal to an analog monitor in years-gone-by could actually damage it. That's all changed now with LCDs etc whose drive circuits are able to detect and display a wide range of resolutions at arbitrary refresh rates. In my experience though the amount of leeway you have is smaller than you'd think and is very dependent on the make and model of the display device...many of them even list slightly different timings in their user manuals! If you want to be sure that your circuit will work on the equipment that your tester runs it on then you should stick to one of the "official" resolutions as accurately as you can.

As far as per-pixel timing goes yes, an 800x600x72Hz signal needs a 50MHz clock and you thus have 20nS in which to fetch your pixel data (that said I'm not 100% sure your sync and porch timings are correct, they're different to the ones at [VGA Timings](http://martin.hinner.info/vga/timing.html) which I've used successfully myself in the past). If 20nS isn't enough then you'll need to use multiple circuits e.g. one for odd pixels and another for evens. Alternatively you can implement pipeline stages, e.g. for the pixel you output at cycle X you read its value from ROM at cycle X-1 and calculate the address to read at cycle X-2. Another trick I've used in the past is to double-buffer the display with 2 lines of RAM i.e. on any given line you are drawing directly from one buffer whilst simultaneously writing to the next; this gives you more time to render each line but typically adds the additional complexity of separate clock domains between rendering and display.